# Using Cloudformation to build environment on new account

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-code-deploy

I'm trying to write some Cloudformation templates to setup a new account with all the resources needed for running our site. In this case we'll be setting up a UAT/test environment.

I have setup:

> 1. VPC
> 2. Security groups
> 3. ElastiCache
> 4. ALB
> 5. RDS
> 6. Auto scaling group

What I'm struggling with is, when I bring up my auto scaling group with our silver AMI, it fails health checks and the auto scaling group gets rolled back.

I have our code in a git repo, which is to be deployed via CodeDeploy, but it seems I can't add a CodeDeploy deployment without an auto scaling group and I can't setup the auto scaling group without CodeDeploy.

Should I modify our silver AMI to fake the health checks so the auto scaling group can be created? Or should I create the auto scaling group without health checks until a later step?

How can I programmatically setup CodeDeploy with Cloudformation so it pulls the latest code from our git repo?

Answer (score 0):

Create the deployment app,  group, etc. when you  create the rest of the infrastructure, via CloudFormation.

One  of the parameters to your  template would be the app package already found in an S3 code deploy bucket, or the Github commit id to a working release of your app.

> In addition to the other methods available to you in CodeDeploy, you can use AWS CloudFormation templates to perform the following tasks: Create applications, Create deployment groups and specify a target revision, Create deployment configurations, Create Amazon EC2 instances.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-cloudformation-templates.html

With this approach you can launch a  working version of your app  as you create your infrastructure. Use normal health checks so you can be sure your app is properly configured.